# app image doesn't load inside a facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, image, redirect, facebook-canvas

I'm developing an app inside a facebook canvas page

here's an example link
http://test.ctag.it/?ctag_events=concerto-queen

When I use the facebook debugger, facebook recognizes all the images, but when I try to post actions or share events inside the canvas it doesn't find the attachment images, only the default app thumbnail. The problem appears to be the incomplete URL redirect facebook initializes.

Is there a way to display apps.facebook.com/xxxxx/?ctag_events=concerto-queen  in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

When I enter your example link into the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it does not find the image (og:image) and other `og:` tags.

Here's what a working page looks like:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fplooza.com%2Fog%2Fshop1.html

(Note the Object Properties Section)

The Debugger (and so the FB scraper) cannot find your `og:` tags. Move them close to the `<head>` tag and it will be able to find them.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="115821641901976">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://test.ctag.it/?ctag_events=concerto-queen">
<meta property="og:title" content="Concerto Queen">
... and other og and fb tags ...
```